# How do I get the conversationId from a RingCentral SMS response?

Tags: php, sms, ringcentral

I am building a simple SMS sending module with the RingCentral WebRTC client in PHP. I can successcully send messages and I get a valid JSON response object, and when I echo it out I can see the conversationId, but I cannot seem to echo it into a variable.

This is my API call:

```
$resp = $this->platform->post('/account/~/extension/~/sms',
array(
    'from' => array ('phoneNumber' => $this->ringcentral_username),
    'to' => array(array('phoneNumber' => $phone)),
    'text' => $message
));
```

I can see:

```
"conversationId" : 1234567890,
```

in the response object, but `$resp->conversationId` is not found. How do I pull that out?

Answer (score 1):

I found it:

```php
$resp->json()->conversationId
```